# Find Android users in your contact list

Tags: java, android

My app has an option to share its content with friends in user's contact list.

However, because it's only available for Android users, is there a way to find out what people in my contact list have an android device?

That way I could present a filtered list to my customers, who may sometimes have thousands of people in their contact book.

I was thinking of filtering only Gmail addresses, but that isn't very good indication of the person being an android owner. I know Google can tell, because they tie devices to Google email addresses (they even know what device and Android version is used by everyone) , but how can I tell?

Comment: Very good Question, I am looking for exactly the same .. closely watching your Question now :)

Comment: Should the content be shared to your app on the other users phone?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you want to share content from your app on the phone of user A to your app on the phone of user B right? So you don't want to use a third party app (like email) to share your content.

I don't think that it is possible to get all contacts that also use your app directly from your contact list. If the scenario I described above is true, you could do it like e.g. WhatsApp or similar Apps.

They upload the contact list of the phone to their servers and compare them against their user database. This way they can identify all users in your contact list that also use the App. You could do it in a similar way to identify all contacts on a users phone that also use your app.

Comment: I want to know who in user's contact list has android device. Not my app!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, but I don't know it for sure.